# Dell Inspiron 15 connects to 4G @ 20Mbps, but to Fibre @ 1.5mbps - other to same fibre @ 20Mbps

Tags: wireless-networking, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 Core i5. It can connect to a 4G Wifi (Huawei E5573) at 20Mbps - no problem.
The same Inspiron on the 2.4Ghz Fibre Router (D-Link DIR 825) only goes to 1.5Mbps.
All other devices to this same Fibre router go to 20Mbps.

I've installed latest Windows 10, updated Drivers for Dell Wireless 1703 802.11b|g|n.
Smartbyte has been removed completely - it is not the problem in this case.
I've restarted the Inspiron many times. 
I've made sure all other 2.4Ghz devices are completely switched off as to not interfere.

Any ideas of what I could look at please?

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe Mode With Networking?

Comment: I performed this action (boot into safe mode with networking), and was able to see both wifi connections in question. I was unable to connect to the internet though - the wifi connection states that it was "connected - no internet"

Comment: Which two wifi connections? And was there Internet on the other one?

Comment: 4g + Fibre wifi connections. No internet available on either one on safe mode with networking. On normal mode (not safe mode) both wifi connections available with internet.

Comment: What is the exact model of the dell? It may look like "Dell Inspiron 15 3000".

Comment: Dell Inspiron 15 3521

Comment: The latest wireless driver is [Dell Wireless 1704/1708 WiFi Driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3521/drivers) from January 2019.